# "Difference to" or "difference with" or "difference from"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

When we use word difference to compare two things, we say for example, 'Difference between Intel and AMD'. However, how can I use word difference with only one thing, for example, what will be correct:

1. Difference with AMD
2. Difference to AMD
3. Difference from AMD

Comment: This is similar to this discussion on the comparision between "different from", "different to" or "different than"- http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516/which-is-correct-is-different-from-or-is-different-than

Comment: Hope [this](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/difference+from) helps.

Answer (score 14):

The correct options are:

> Difference with AMD is...
>   Different to ...
>   Different from...

"Difference with AMD is..." used when stating a characteristic of AMD that is unique or different from other similar objects. No real comparison is being made.

"Different to" and "Different from" are used intentionally to make comparisons, between another similar object, and "AMD". But, if you aren't comparing two things, then the second two options cannot be used. They are used only when comparing.

Comment: The second two options are incorrect when *not* comparing two explicit things.

Comment: I think the OP is asking about "Difference to~" and "DIfference than~", not "Different to~" and "Difference than~".

Comment: What about the case of "The difference between Intel and AMD is smaller than their difference <???> XYZ"?