# Shall I put the adjective behind the noun in this case?

Tags: grammar, expressions

"Function"  means the performance of something, so it is on a level different from "project".(self-made)

Here what I mean is that the two words are on different levels, the first may refer to potential things, the latter refers only to real things. But I do not know exactly how to use "different from" properly. Shall I say directly that "it is on a different level from "project"?

Answer (score 1):

Either one is fine, but I would use "different level from 'project'". The other way, what you're really saying is "a level [that is] different from 'project'", and the omission makes it sound a bit awkward to me.

See also: [Which is correct: “__ is different from **” or “** is different than __”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516/which-is-correct-is-different-from-or-is-different-than)