# Use of from vs. than

Tags: word-choice

Years ago I knew the distinction between "this book is different from that one" and "this book is longer than that one."  How do you choose?

Comment: You could have a look here: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516/which-is-correct-is-different-from-or-is-different-than

Answer (score 0):

"different from" is the normal thing, but in BrE you can also use different to sth, and  in AmE different than sth. After comparative you always use than.
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/different?q=different