# SAT Grammar Question - Comparisons

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, comparisons

I have a question on comparisons.

[image]

I said no error first, and that was wrong. I don't see an error with B or D or
A. Is it C "being"? Should it be switched to be?

Comment: I would say "preferable to  living".

Comment: In the English that I speak it would be "preferable **to**" You wouldn't say, "I prefer tea than  coffee" it would be "I prefer tea to coffee."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the quesion is about the right choice without any research/reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proper preposition for part D is "to" so it should be "was preferable to living".  "Than" should be used to indicate which is greater, such as "was more preferable than".

Comment: +1 for making the connection with 'more'.

Comment: But I've noticed that Americans on this site nearly always say *different than*. Do you say *different than* or as I would *George is different to John*?

Comment: @WS2 - If you add 'more'  then even Brits say 'different than'. Example: John is different but Jane is even more different than John."

Comment: Please don't induce scope creep in answers/comments. There's already a question about [different than](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/516/which-is-correct-is-different-from-or-is-different-than).

Comment: @chaslyfromUK But that *than* is a dependent of *more* not directly a dependent of *different*. Consider *John is different **to**  Bill, but Jane is more different **to** Bill than John is.*

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Yes, there may possibly be people in Britain who say that, but I wouldn't. I would say *Jane is even more different to Bill*

Answer (score 2):

D

*preferable to* living with a lie

See, for example, the sentences in the [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/preferable)

See also [preferable to/than](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/preferable-to-than.614722/)